How to implement a primitive spin lock in pure C
I have been trying with multiple tutorials to implement a simple spin lock in pure c (i.e. with no OS specific stuff).
This is the last i have come up with
myFile.c
static atomic_flag mg_lockAllBuffers = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;


    /**
     * @brief Busy blocks infinite until the buffer is unlocked
     * @param pHandle - Pointer to the buffer
     */
    static inline void waitAndLockConcurrentAccess();
    
    /**
     * @brief unlocks the buffer
     * @param pHandle - Pointer to the buffer
     */
    static inline void unlockConcurrentAccess();
    
    static inline void waitAndLockConcurrentAccess()
    {
      // Atomic load
      int dummy = 0;
      while (atomic_flag_test_and_set(&mg_lockAllBuffers))
      {
        // busy wait
        dummy++;
      }
    }
    
    
    static inline void unlockConcurrentAccess()
    {
      atomic_flag_clear(&mg_lockAllBuffers);
    }

However GCCs thread sanitiser is complaining about a data race within waitAndLockConcurrentAccess(). But I do not know why.
Read of size 8 at 0x7f3e05b45ed0 by thread T2:
Previous write of size 8 at 0x7f3e05b45ed0 by thread T1:

Could you help we out here?
thx guys

all cppreference.com examples on this I could find use the two-parameter version of atomic_flag_test_and_set. I don't really understand what the one-parameter-version does

ah, the default is memory_order_seq_cst which is explained at https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order

How do you call all of this? If gcc is complaining it might be because it inlined the whole thing in unexpected ways.

What object is at 0x7f3e05b45ed0 ? You only show two variables here, and neither can have a datarace - one is only accessed atomically, and the other is a local variable.

i have tried the example from here with the explicit. But same fail result :O https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_flag_test_and_set. I'm calling this like a mutex waitAndLockConcurrentAccess() //do some code unlockConcurrentAccess()

0x7f3e05b45ed0 this is the atomic flag mg_lockAllBuffers

Please present a complete [mre] that we can build and test ourselves.  What you show now does not seem consistent with the diagnostic you receive, but it's hard to be sure that there isn't some confounding factor that you have not presented.

@JHeni are you really showing us all accesses to this atomic_flag? The two functions you show cannot produce a datarace in the way that I understand the term, because both are atomic. If those really are the only accesses to the variable, then I suppose this may be a false positive. Can you show the entire message from the sanitizer?

and for completeness, show how you compile & run your code with the sanitizer enabled.
